# 2D Point identification/matching on a continous loop with new and old points

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I'm working on a dart project. I am detecting darts with a laser scanner. Using K-Means I am able to detect the dart clusters. I am scanning from the point a player starts his turn. This means I have the most scan points for the first dart and the least for the last one. I detect a dart hit with a vibration sensor. I am running K-Means on a loop so my calculated dart points get more accurate over time hence to more scan points every run.

Now I would like to assign my cluster centers to the dart number. I tried caring over the cluster centers from the last run to have the same cluster centers order every time but without a smart way of generating a center for the new dart I often run into the problem of K-Means halfing an existing cluster due to being bigger.

I am searching for an algorithm that allows me to assign the center to an id (0, 1, ...). If there is a new cluster it gets a new id. I want to run this algorithm AFTER running K-Means so it only works with the cluster centers.
I guess I could simple calculate the distances between the old and the new points and identificate them that way. The one remaining is the new dart point.

I would also be open switching from K-Means to another clustering algo if that helps.

I hope you understand the problem I am facing. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right, you need to assign one set of cluster centers to another and use the centers' locations only. This problem is called minimum weight matching or linear sum assignment problem. First, you need to calculate the cost matrix, i.e., the distance matrix between cluster centers of the two sets. Then you use this matrix to find the assignment with the minimal overall distance. Scipy library has functions for this kind of problems:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
dists = distance.cdist(centers1, centers2, 'euclidean')
indices1, indices2 = linear_sum_assignment(dists)
```

The remaining indices are the new clusters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I was searching for. If I understand it correctly cour indicies1 are my old centers and indicies2 are my new centers.